# testing controller with spec and factory girl, can't sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot, functional-testing

I'm newbie on rails and testing rails applications. I try to test an existing rails application with rspec.
 I've just finished model tests and i have to complete controller tests too.
But i have a problem with sign_in method on rspec. I've tried all solution methods on the internet but still i can't sign in like a user with rspec.
here is the my controller code, it's too simple;

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def how_it_works
  end

  def what_is
  end

  def creative_tips
  end

  def brand_tips
  end

  def we_are
  end

  def faq
  end
end
```

and here is the my spec code;

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AboutController do

  before(:all) do
    @customer=Factory.create(:customer)
    sign_in @customer
  end

  context 'index page :' do

    it 'should be loaded successfully' do
      response.should be_success
    end

  end

end
```

Here is the my factory code;

```
Factory.define :unconfirmed_user, :class => User do |u|
  u.sequence(:user_name) {|n| "user_#{n}"}
  u.sequence(:email){|n| "user__#{n}@example.com"}
  u.sequence(:confirmation_token){|n| "confirm_#{n}"}
  u.sequence(:reset_password_token){|n| "password_#{n}"}
  u.password '123456'
  u.password_confirmation '123456'
  u.user_type :nil
end

Factory.define :user, :parent => :unconfirmed_user do |u|
  u.confirmed_at '1-1-2010'
  u.confirmation_sent_at '1-1-2010'
end

Factory.define :customer, :parent => :user do |u|
  u.user_type :customer
end
```

Finally here is the my spec_helper code

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment" unless defined?(Rails)
require 'rspec/rails'
require "paperclip/matchers"

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

gem file;

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
.
.
.
gem "devise" , "1.1.5"
.
.
.

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.11.0"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

and here is the error;

```
Failures:

  1) AboutController index page : should be loaded successfully
     Failure/Error: sign_in @customer
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/about_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

solution must be too easy but I'm newbie on rails and i can't find it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the sign-in step inside the `it` block in order for rspec to be able to access the response, e.g.:

```
it 'should be loaded successfully' do
  sign_in @customer
  response.should be_success
end
```

Comment: now its working :D thank you man. But why the sign_in method don't work on before block?

Comment: Actually I believe that if you put the `sign_in @customer` into a normal `before` block (and not a `before(:all)` block) it should also work. `before(:all)` is run before all tests and so I don't think the response is carried on into the first test (or any others for that matter).

Comment: Also, to be clear, if you want to check that the index page is loading, you'd probably want to add a `get :index` before you check the response. As is what it's checking is that the response from your `sign_in @customer` step is successful.

Comment: and i have another question; setup block don't work in context block on my specs. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I think you should post another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have no subject.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AboutController do

  before(:all) do
    @customer=Factory.create(:customer)
    sign_in @customer
  end

  context 'index page :' do

    subject { Page }    
    it 'should be loaded successfully' do
      response.should be_success
    end

  end

end
```

You might need to `visit customers_path`.

Comment: You don't need to have a subject defined to check that the response is successful.